# Linux for a writer, running on a Pentium II

Tags: linux, small-distribution, word-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux for low-end hardware and internet browsing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/linux-for-low-end-hardware-and-internet-browsing)

My dad has a rather old computer that's just sitting there that I want to repurpose. Now I know could probably get a Pentium 4 very cheap but where's the fun in that?

What I'm after is something that's simple to use that will run on a Pentium II or III (I can't remember) with 4GB of HDD space and probably about 512MB of RAM.

What can I install on this to make it work?

Comment: The electricity use of an old machine over one year may justify a new machine... but that's not the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a quick read of [this techradar article](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/8-of-the-best-tiny-linux-distros-683552).

Classic distribution for old machines: [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/).

Look at Markdown/LaTeX for nice formatting of documents, but very low memory consumption whilst writing.

Answer (score 2):

There are many lightweight Linux distributions out there. Some that spring to mind are:
- Crunchbang
- Lubuntu

Or even more lightweight:
- SliTaz
- Puppy Linux
- Damn Small Linux