# Suggestions for a GUI light distribution

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

**I am looking for a scaled down version of Linux/Unix**

I am looking for the most scaled down distribution of Linux/Unix that I can install on an old computer. Features listed below.

- Minimal GUI: Preferably a command line environment where all image files are  handled by something similar to Delphi.
- Dependencies: I would like the OS/dist. to be able to handle .txt files 
  and some image files from the get go.
- Preferably some compatibility with modern systems: For example, the possibility to use Synaptic, or equivalent, to download Latex packages and compile from the command line/terminal without errors.
- Minimal amount of structure when installed: The difference between this question and [Unix without a GUI for old machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43552/unix-without-a-gui-for-old-machine) is that I don't need the distribution to be usable "out of the box".

What I am looking for is the least squares projection of all the properties above.

Comment: If you would be so polite to read the  [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), you would no that on this Q&A site we abhos the use of chit-chat ("Thank you in advance" and that you are a basic user and your studying goals"). Your name does not have  to be in the post when it is already below it next to your avatar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you need a minimal distro which ships with just linux.

You will find [Siltaz](http://www.slitaz.org/en/about/) quite useful. It is quite minimal and when loaded through a cd you have the option to remove the cd and still use the distro as it loads completely on the ram.

This feature is quite recommended if you don't want to blow your PC out.
Also its just **30mb** small, cool little distro.

If you need a more functional distro try [Alpine](http://alpinelinux.org/).

**note** Siltaz is not that beginner friendly as other distros but packs quite a punch.